# Create PHP list of random numbers. Label 25+ High, -25 Low

Tags: php, random, count, while-loop, echo

I'm trying to teach myself PHP by finding random challenges on the internet. I found this:
http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/a/Create-A-Program-That.htm

He has the "answer" listed on that page but it doesn't make sense. He even makes mention of a part of code that isn't there. The (1, 50) piece he talks about isn't in his solution. I did it but I'm trying to make my code elegant and understand another approach.

This was my approach:

```
<?php

     $count = 0;
     while ($count <= 10)
    {
     $random= rand(1, 50);
     if ($random >= 25)
     {echo $random."- High, </b>";}
     elseif ($random < 25)
     {echo $random."- Low, </b>";}

     $count++; //increment by 1
    }

?>
```

Comment: The code on his page doesn't even work. He must have messed up the entry of the HTML characters or something as there are multiple things wrong. As for your code, it is pretty solid. You missed the part where if it is 25 exactly, don't output anything, but it is clear and to the point. Not much else to wish for in a while loop.

Comment: I was about to say the same as tatorface. I double checked the source as well and the missing chunks aren't even there (not hidden in a tag). It's almost as if it trying to be a "fill in the blanks" with code.

Comment: Given that it's on about.com, it's a miracle that it's even somewhat readable...

Comment: Wow, that's quite pathetic... Even for about.com

Comment: Also, according to the requirements, if the number is exactly 25, you aren't supposed to echo out anything next to the number. Other than that, given the supplied example, you are pretty much right on for what that tutorial is teaching.

Comment: Yea, I thought it was going to be cool to see more challenges. I can't even understand how to go to the next PHP challenge. All I see is a Ruby challenge. Bleh. But thanks for verifying what I suspected. I guess I'll look elsewhere for beginner challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that elegant enough for you?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $random = rand(1, 50);
    echo $random . ($random >= 25 ? "- High": "- Low") . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I think it had to be a While Loop but I like the way this is written too. Looks very clean.

Comment: then like this:  $count = 10;
while ($count--) {
    $random = rand(1, 50);
    echo $random . ($random >= 25 ? "- High": "- Low") . '<br/>';
}